# How to put a TextView over RecyclerView items in Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

As shown in below image I made it with [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView).

[image]

I want approach to a solution to add a TextView that is shown over the RecyclerView items like the image below.

[image]

As you can see this TextView is laid on over two or more items of RecyclerView, so how I can achieve this?

Comment: vazeh tar bego shayad tonsetam komaket konam

Answer (score 1):

```
  <TextView
      
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Appointment made 8.15-9.15"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

add this to your activity layout .xml file above recycler view.